# Count frequency of item in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, generator

I have a list of tuples as shown below. I have to count how many items have a number greater than 1. The code that I have written so far is very slow. Even if there are around 10K tuples, if you see below example string appears two times, so i have to get such kind of strings. My question is what is the best way to achieve the count of strings here by iterating over the generator

List:

```
 b_data=[('example',123),('example-one',456),('example',987),.....]
```

My code so far:

```
blockslst=[]
for line in b_data:
    blockslst.append(line[0])

blocklstgtone=[]
for item in blockslst:
    if(blockslst.count(item)>1):
        blocklstgtone.append(item)
```

Comment: By the way, that isn't a generator expression, it's a list.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've got the right idea extracting the first item from each tuple. You can make your code more concise using a list/generator comprehension, as I show you below.

From that point on, the most idiomatic manner to find frequency counts of elements is using a `collections.Counter` object.

1. Extract the first elements from your list of tuples (using a comprehension)
2. Pass this to `Counter`
3. Query count of `example`

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(x[0] for x in b_data)
print(counts['example'])
```

Sure, you can use `list.count` if it’s only *one* item you want to find frequency counts for, but in the general case, a `Counter` is the way to go.

---

The advantage of a `Counter` is it performs frequency counts of *all* elements (not just `example`) in linear (`O(N)`) time. Say you also wanted to query the count of another element, say `foo`. That would be done with -

```
print(counts['foo'])
```

If `'foo'` doesn’t exist in the list, `0` is returned.

If you want to find the most common elements, call `counts.most_common` -

```
print(counts.most_common(n))
```

Where `n` is the number of elements you want to display. If you want to see everything, don't pass `n`.

---

To retrieve counts of most common elements, one efficient way to do this is to query `most_common` and then extract all elements with counts over 1, efficiently with `itertools`.

```
from itertools import takewhile

l = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4, 6, 7, 7, 8, 3, 3, 2, 1]
c = Counter(l)

list(takewhile(lambda x: x[-1] > 1, c.most_common()))
[(1, 5), (3, 4), (2, 3), (7, 2)]
```

(OP edit) Alternatively, use a *list comprehension* to get a list of items having count > 1 -

```
[item[0] for item in counts.most_common() if item[-1] > 1]
```

Keep in mind that this isn’t as efficient as the `itertools.takewhile` solution. For example, if you have one item with count > 1, and a million items with count equal to 1, you’d end up iterating over the list a million and one times, when you don’t have to (because `most_common` returns frequency counts in descending order). With `takewhile` that isn’t the case, because you stop iterating as soon as the condition of count > 1 becomes false.

Comment: Most common method, is there way it can give me all the strings like example having count > 1

Comment: @min2bro Yes, why not. query `most_common`, and iterate over with a loop. Let me write up a small answer.

Comment: Thanks for `Counter` - did not know that one and recreated it the same as Ayodhyankit Paul did

Comment: @coldspeed, Added the list comprehension to only get the list of Strings having count greater than 1

Comment: @cs95 I have a question about `list(takewhile(lambda x: x[-1] > 1, c.most_common()))`...How do you reset the counter when inside a for loop? For the life of me I can't reset it. I have tried c.clear(), c.update('a'), c = Counter()..But nothing resets the counter. It just keeps adding and adding...

Answer (score 3):

First method :

> **What about without loop ?**

```
print(list(map(lambda x:x[0],b_data)).count('example'))
```

output:

```
2
```

Second method :

You can calculate using simple dict , without importing any external module or without making it so complex:

```
b_data = [('example', 123), ('example-one', 456), ('example', 987)]

dict_1={}
for i in b_data:
    if i[0] not in dict_1:
        dict_1[i[0]]=1
    else:
        dict_1[i[0]]+=1

print(dict_1)



print(list(filter(lambda y:y!=None,(map(lambda x:(x,dict_1.get(x)) if dict_1.get(x)>1 else None,dict_1.keys())))))
```

output:

```
[('example', 2)]
```

> Test_case :

```
b_data = [('example', 123), ('example-one', 456), ('example', 987),('example-one', 456),('example-one', 456),('example-two', 456),('example-two', 456),('example-two', 456),('example-two', 456)]
```

output:

```
[('example-two', 4), ('example-one', 3), ('example', 2)]
```

Comment: The only problem here is that I need to again iterate over the dict_1 dictionary to find the strings having count greater than 1

Comment: @min2bro i have update the  solution now check , you even don't need loop there or any external module.

Comment: I am looking for all the strings which have count > 1, so the above solution works for one string count at a time

Comment: Your code is just a re-implementation of `Counter`. Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ i don't know about `Counter`  , never use that ,  I just wrote my own logic .

Comment: @min2bro if you want for all string then go with my second solution , and yeah i fixed that issue now you don't have to iterate over dic_t dictionary to find the strings having count greater than 1 check .

Answer (score 2):

> Time it took me to do this
>   [ayodhyankit-paul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5904928/ayodhyankit-paul)
>   posted the same - leaving it in non the less for the generator code
>   for testcases and timing:

Creating **100001** items took roughly 5 seconds, counting took about **0.3s**,
filtering on counts was too fast to measure (with datetime.now() - did not bother with [perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)) - all in all it took **less then 5.1s** from start to finish for about 10 times the data you operate on.

I think this similar to what `Counter` in [COLDSPEED](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%e1%b4%8f%ca%9f%e1%b4%85s%e1%b4%98%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%87%e1%b4%85)s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843727/7505395) does:

foreach `item` in `list of tuples`:

- if `item[0]` not in list, put into `dict` with `count of 1`
- else `increment count` in dict `by 1`

Code:

```
from collections import Counter
import random
from datetime import datetime # good enough for a loong running op


dt_datagen = datetime.now()
numberOfKeys = 100000 


# basis for testdata
textData = ["example", "pose", "text","someone"]
numData = [random.randint(100,1000) for _ in range(1,10)] # irrelevant

# create random testdata from above lists
tData = [(random.choice(textData)+str(a%10),random.choice(numData)) for a in range(numberOfKeys)] 

tData.append(("aaa",99))

dt_dictioning = datetime.now()

# create a dict
countEm = {}

# put all your data into dict, counting them
for p in tData:
    if p[0] in countEm:
        countEm[p[0]] += 1
    else:
        countEm[p[0]] = 1

dt_filtering = datetime.now()
#comparison result-wise (commented out)        
#counts = Counter(x[0] for x in tData)
#for c in sorted(counts):
#    print(c, " = ", counts[c])
#print()  
# output dict if count > 1
subList = [x for x in countEm if countEm[x] > 1] # without "aaa"

dt_printing = datetime.now()

for c in sorted(subList):
    if (countEm[c] > 1):
        print(c, " = ", countEm[c])

dt_end = datetime.now()

print( "\n\nCreating ", len(tData) , " testdataitems took:\t", (dt_dictioning-dt_datagen).total_seconds(), " seconds")
print( "Putting them into dictionary took \t", (dt_filtering-dt_dictioning).total_seconds(), " seconds")
print( "Filtering donw to those > 1 hits took \t", (dt_printing-dt_filtering).total_seconds(), " seconds")
print( "Printing all the items left took    \t", (dt_end-dt_printing).total_seconds(), " seconds")

print( "\nTotal time: \t", (dt_end- dt_datagen).total_seconds(), " seconds" )
```

Output:

```
# reformatted for bevity
example0  =  2520       example1  =  2535       example2  =  2415
example3  =  2511       example4  =  2511       example5  =  2444
example6  =  2517       example7  =  2467       example8  =  2482
example9  =  2501

pose0  =  2528          pose1  =  2449          pose2  =  2520      
pose3  =  2503          pose4  =  2531          pose5  =  2546          
pose6  =  2511          pose7  =  2452          pose8  =  2538          
pose9  =  2554

someone0  =  2498       someone1  =  2521       someone2  =  2527
someone3  =  2456       someone4  =  2399       someone5  =  2487
someone6  =  2463       someone7  =  2589       someone8  =  2404
someone9  =  2543

text0  =  2454          text1  =  2495          text2  =  2538
text3  =  2530          text4  =  2559          text5  =  2523      
text6  =  2509          text7  =  2492          text8  =  2576      
text9  =  2402


Creating  100001  testdataitems took:    4.728604  seconds
Putting them into dictionary took        0.273245  seconds
Filtering donw to those > 1 hits took    0.0  seconds
Printing all the items left took         0.031234  seconds

Total time:      5.033083  seconds
```

Comment: @COOLDSPEED mentions in other answer that this is about what Counter does internally - so dont use mine, use `Counter` ;) my guess would be it works even smarter.

Comment: I can still appreciate a well put together answer. Upvoted, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example to make you understand.Although this example is very much different than your example, I found it very helpful while solving these type of questions.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [
(0, "Hadoop"), (0, "Big Data"), (0, "HBase"), (0, "Java"),
(1, "Postgres"), (2, "Python"), (2, "scikit-learn"), (2, "scipy"),
(2, "numpy"), (2, "statsmodels"), (2, "pandas"), (3, "R"), (3, "Python"),
(3, "statistics"), (3, "regression"), (3, "probability"),
(4, "machine learning"), (4, "regression"), (4, "decision trees"),
(4, "libsvm"), (5, "Python"), (5, "R"), (5, "Java"), (5, "C++"),
(5, "Haskell"), (5, "programming languages"), (6, "statistics"),
(6, "probability"), (6, "mathematics"), (6, "theory"),
(7, "machine learning"), (7, "scikit-learn"), (7, "Mahout"),
(7, "neural networks"), (8, "neural networks"), (8, "deep learning"),
(8, "Big Data"), (8, "artificial intelligence"), (9, "Hadoop"),
(9, "Java"), (9, "MapReduce"), (9, "Big Data")
]
# 
# 1. Lowercase everything
# 2. Split it into words.
# 3. Count the results.

dictionary = Counter(word for i, j in a for word in j.lower().split())

print(dictionary)

# print out every words if the count > 1
[print(word, count) for word, count in dictionary.most_common() if count > 1]
```

Now this is your example solved in the above manner

```
from collections import Counter
a=[('example',123),('example-one',456),('example',987),('example2',987),('example3',987)]

dict = Counter(word for i,j in a for word in i.lower().split() )

print(dict)

[print(word ,count) for word,count in dict.most_common() if count > 1  ]
```