# Find the frequency of every unique elements in tuple(without using any list concept) and concatenate with its word

Tags: python, tuples, concatenation, word-frequency

I've tried the following code:

```
print("Entered tuple :",tup)
for x in tup :
    val=(x,)
    count=0
    for y in tup :
        if(x==y):
            count+=1
    temp=(x,count)
    freq+=(temp,)
print("\nPrinting tuple in (tuple element,frequency) format : \n")  
print(freq)
```

Actual output for the above code :

```
Entered tuple : ('1', '2', '3', '4', '1')
Printing tuple in (tuple element,frequency) format element : 
(('1', 2), ('2', 1), ('3', 1), ('4', 1), ('1', 2))
```

In tuple, 1 is repeated 2 times and it also displayed in results 2 times.But it'll be displayed only once in the result.

Expected output is :

```
Entered tuple : ('1', '2', '3', '4', '1')
Printing tuple in (tuple element,frequency) format element : 
(('1', 2), ('2', 1), ('3', 1), ('4', 1))
```

Comment: You can just use `Counter(tup)` (I'm sure this is a duplicate..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count frequency of item in a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843707/count-frequency-of-item-in-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: `tuple(Counter(('1', '2', '3', '4', '1')).items())`

Comment: Thanks @Sayse. Got the expected one :)

Comment: Why do you want to "not use any list concept"? And what exactly does that *mean*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel lots of way to find frequency of unique elements in python data structure. I almost practised with other data structure, but for tuples alone, i didn't get what i need.  :)

Answer (score 1):

1) I've import the collections module in my code.

```
from collections import Counter
```

2) Counter(tup) in loop.

```
for x in Counter(tup) :
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Entered tuple : ('33', '77', '44', '77', '33')
Printing tuple in in (tuple element,frequency) format  : 
(('33', 2), ('77', 2), ('44', 1))
```